# IRC user configuration for irssi/ircd-hybrid on Debian

Tags: debian, irc, ircd

Running programs as root is dangerous, What's the best way to create a new low privileged user for Irssi and ircd-hybird on Debian?

Comment: running a program as root is not dangerous as long as you know what you are doing

Comment: @angs: That is bad security. If a program is vulnerable, an attacker may be able to execute arbitrary code with the privledges of the user running the program.

Comment: @Evan Teitelman, what I meant, I am not agreed with the generalization of the statement. Running a program as root is not always dangerous, If you know how to use a program, e.g. screen, would it be dangerous to connect my serial device via screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200.

Comment: @angs: I see. I thought you were going for "it's not dangerous if you don't make mistakes."

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `useradd` command.

```
useradd -s /bin/false -g <primary_group> <username>
```

The `-s` flag sets the user's login shell. If the user does not need a shell, set its login shell to `/bin/false` or `/bin/nologin`.

If the user needs a home directory, you can use the `-m` flag to create one automatically. You can run programs as this user with `sudo`.

```
sudo -u <username> <program>
```